# How to set expiration time for a new table in BigQuery created from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a script to crate new Google BigQuery table from Google Apps Script project.
When I run it with default expiration time it works well.
But now I want to set expiration time equal 2 hours (7200000ms)

```js
function createNewTable(tableId){  
  var table = {
    expirationTime: "7200000",
    tableReference: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId
    }    
  }
  table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
  console.info('Table created: %s', table.id);
}
```

It does not work because an error `API call to bigquery.tables.insert failed with error: Expiration time must be at least 1 seconds in the future`.
Where I'wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you send `7200000` instead of `"7200000"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

You should provide the number of milliseconds since the epoch, not since the present moment. From BigQuery [table resource docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables):

> **expirationTime**: Optional. The time when this table expires, **in milliseconds since the epoch**.

#### Solution:

Get the milliseconds since epoch till the present moment, and add the two hours to this:

```
var expirationTime = 7200000 + new Date().getTime();
```

If necessary, parse it to string when setting the request body: `expirationTime: expirationTime.toString()`.